# How to use gaurds on module level in nest.js?

Tags: module, nestjs

**I want to use the gaurds on module level instead of controller routes and global module.
How can I do that?**

I have this gaurd on my code:

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private readonly verifyOptions?: VerifySessionOptions) {}
  async canActivate(context: ExecutionContext): Promise<boolean> {
    const ctx = context.switchToHttp();

    let err = undefined;
    const resp = ctx.getResponse();
    await verifySession(this.verifyOptions)(ctx.getRequest(), resp, (res) => {
      err = res;
    });
    if (resp.headersSent) {
      throw new STError({
        message: 'RESPONSE_SENT',
        type: 'RESPONSE_SENT',
      });
    }
    if (err) {
      throw err;
    }
    return true;
  }
}
```

I have many modules in my app like applications, chat, share etc and I want to protect the routes. For that protected routes I want to use this AuthGaurd.

But I don't want to use the gaurd on each and every controller endpoint like this:

```
@Post()
  UseGaurds(new AuthGaurd())
  async createApplication(
    @Body() createAppData: CreateApplicationDto,
    @Session() session: SessionContainer
  ) {
    try {
      const newDoc = await this.applicationService.create(createAppData);
      return utils.sendSuccess(SUCCESS.S200.DEFAULT, newDoc);
    } catch (error) {
      throw new BadRequestException();
    }
  }
```

I want to use the gaurd on module level. Not on the global module but the modules like application, chat, share etc.
This is what my applicationModule looks like:

```
@Module({
  imports: [SequelizeModule.forFeature([Application])],
  providers: [ApplicationServices, ...applicationProvider, ...shareProvider],
  exports: [ApplicationServices],
  controllers: [ApplicationController],
})
export class ApplicationModule {}
```